# German citizenship - Complex case

Tags: germany, citizenship

My question is the following:
My great-grandparents were German. They never lost their citizenship. My grandmother was born in 1930 in Argentina (ius soli) and got married in 1950 to an Argentine (also of German descent, but no way to prove it).
My mother was born in 1954, so she couldn't become German by birth. Recently, a possibility opened for her and me to become German via naturalization. 
However, this is where it gets complicated:

1) All the information available applies to people living abroad, while I am currently living in Germany

2) [Here](https://uk.diplo.de/uk-en/02/citizenship/loss-of-citizenship) I have read that women marrying men between 1949 and 1953 lost their German citizenship if they didn't become stateless. My grandmother would fit this typology, meaning, she lost her German citizenship. This would mean that my mother would be in an even worse situation than I thought previously.

3) However, [here](https://australien.diplo.de/blob/2075954/f3f6be72a3a87209554979f385e9466f/art-116-information-data.pdf) I read that "A descendant born after a parent was deprived of his/her German citizenship and before the
parent's citizenship was restored also has a claim under Article 116 (2) of the Basic Law. This,
however, applies only if the descendant would have acquired German citizenship by birth under
the prevailing provisions of the Reich and Citizenship Law (RuStAG) or the Citizenship Law
(StAG), had his/her father or mother or his/her grandfather or grandmother not been deprived of
German citizenship."

I have read the StAG and don't know, whether it applies or not. I can't find the full text of the RuStAG. My questions are, then:

a) Does "restoration" equal "naturalization" or is it as if the citizenship were never lost?

b) Does my grandmother have a right to restore her citizenship or not?

c) Do I get the chance to get the citizenship by birth, in case my grandmother would be able to "restore" her citizenship?

d) Do I get the chance to apply for discretionary naturalization [based on this](https://buenos-aires.diplo.de/ar-de/service/03-Staatsangehoerigkeit/ermessenseinbuergerung/1995630), in case the former is negative? If yes, what are the differences for the groups of people in my situation applying from abroad, and people like me who are already living in Germany?

Any ideas would be appreciated!